# How do I provide "hidden" menu options in my Android app?

Tags: android

I'd like to add a "hidden" or "developer only" menu option to my Android app for debugging purposes — basically I just want a menu option which, when selected, copies the apps database out to a file somewhere on the users disk.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I'd prefer something that's hidden normally but can be enabled "out in the field", but something that requires a quick and easy compilation flag would be OK too.

Comment: You can put some swipe action on setting preferences like like Jelly Bean 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my knowledge there is no developer only option to do exclusive things in Android. You can derive your own i.e. - 10 time click on specific View, specific gesture on any activity. Its up to you!